# Ocultar objetos de Adobe Animate mediante variable, desde EaselJS

Tags: html5, actionscript, easeljs, createjs

Estoy empezando con EaselJS, Animate y HTML5 y no encuentro forma para que se oculten una serie de objetos del stage con nombres con numeración secuencial: obj01, obj02, obj03...

```js
for (hhh = 1; hhh < 10; hhh++) {
 
 this["obj0"+hhh].visible = false;
 
}
```

¿Podría alguien echarme una mano?

Comment: nos compartes tus obj ?  this a que está haciendo referencia en ése ámbito ? por lo que veo la concatenación está bien

Comment: El problema es que `this["obj0"+hhh]` es undefined, nulo, vacío...

Comment: ¿intentaste `.visible = false`? (ahora dice true)

Comment: Sí, con false debería ponerlo invisible, y de echo si pongo: 'this["obj0"+2].visible=false'          me desaparece el obj02,     pero si quiero hacerlo utililzando hhh no hace nada.

Comment: BUENO, gracias a los comentarios encontré que efectivamente estaba definida en this pero debería hacerlo en root y así funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias amigos ;-)

Comment: Hola @Jotajavi. Si encontraste la respuesta a tu pregunta, quizás podrías publicarlo como respuesta para que otro con tu mismo problema pueda ver la solución

Answer (score 0):

Pues al final me funcionó de esta forma:

`var root=this;

for (hhh = 1; hhh < 4; hhh++) {
root["obj0" + hhh].on("pressmove", function (evt) { 
var p = this.parent.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, evt.stageY); 
evt.currentTarget.x = p.x; 
evt.currentTarget.y = p.y;
 })
 root["obj0" + hhh].on("pressup", function (evt) {
 this.alpha = 1;
 }) 
}`